# Why is PHP Treating Carriage Return / Linefeed Combo as a Single Byte?

Tags: php

I have a php script that truncates a string at 41 bytes. I call strlen on the string to check its size. However, if the string has a "\r\n" combo, this combo is treated as one byte. So in my case instead of 42 bytes, PHP thinks it is 41 bytes.

Also substr truncates it to 42 instead of 41 bytes.

```
  if (strlen($value) > 41)
  {
   $value = substr($value, 0, 41);
```

Another weird condition. I have a large set of data I am passing through this function. Thousands of strings. If I use a simpler test data set then the code works correctly, treating "\r\n" as 2 bytes.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: That is a carriage-return line-feed combo, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code in which you prepare the value? i.e. your test case(s)?

Comment: Can't reproduce here on 5.3.4, `strlen` of a 40 chars string + `\r\n` returns 42 as expected. What's your PHP version?

Comment: NetCoder - The version is 5.2.9. But as I said I don't see the behavior always, only on a specific data set that is thousands of strings long. Simpler data sets show the expected behavior. So I'm not convinced 5.3.4 would work.

Comment: Brian Lacy - I can't, because the test case is several MB in size. If I try a certain 42 byte string that fails in that case, then the same string will work in a simple test case.

Comment: Just tried with a 1GB long string, with plenty of `\r\n`, also works as expected.

Comment: Disclose your plattform and usage. If you read the data from a file on Windows, it will convert `\r\n` into `\n` unless you used the `b` flag on `fopen`. So if the 42 byte assumption stems from the filesize or `fread` length, then it's not going to match on strlen.

Comment: Mario - Your comment is making me think. But I still think that's not the issue. I'm running on Windows with Xampp. I read in the string from a database (varchar) and the database has the \r\n. Then I truncate using the above code, and pass it to php xml DomDocument, where it is sent to 3rd party software Quickbooks. Quickbooks sees that the string is too long (42 bytes) and doesn't accept it.

Comment: Look at the hex value of each byte you're looking at.  That'll likely clue you in to what's going on.  (To get the hex value of each bute of a string: `for ($i=0, $n=strlen($string);$i<$n;$i++) { echo dec2hex(ord($string[$i])) . ' '; }`  Note that this will only work if you have [mbstring function overloading](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) disabled...

Comment: how are the values entered into the database? For Example: end users entering data in through a webpage. The reason I ask is that each OS enters the carriage return or newline differently. I believe Mac OSX uses the \r *nix uses the \n and Windows uses \r\n

Comment: Thanks Mario I'm pretty sure you nailed it actually. It's not the PHP functions but rather my testing is flawed because my test tools are inserting carriage returns after the fact. This doesn't explain why Quickbooks thinks the strings are longer, only on this certain dataset. But I don't think it's a php issue anymore.

Comment: @user564189: Try manually creating a string 41 characters long with an ending `\r` character.  It might be QuickBooks that is adding the `\n`.  Either case, just add a `rtrim($string, "\r\n");` to get rid of the trailing charaters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the combo \r\n to \n , do whatever u need , then revert all \n's to the combo ...

```
str_replace("\r\n","\n",$value);
if (strlen($value) > 41)
  {
   $value = substr($value, 0, 41);
str_replace("\n","\r\n",$value);
```

hope this will work for you not knowing what are you trying to do

Comment: Hi Ronan, I've considered this option but I really want to know what's going on. I'm guessing there might be another character combo that gives the same problem that I don't know about yet.

Comment: it's just the `strlen` sees the combo as it's displayed (one character) because it was built to see how many SPACE it will take on the monitor , so they coded it to see the combo as one character , the substr uses the memory block to identify the character without even trying to identify what it is

Comment: strlen usually sees this combo as 2 characters. In all of my simple test cases it is seen as 2 characters. It is only with my large data set that it is seen as 1 character.

Comment: are you sure the large dataset really has \r\n ? and not \n ? . if yes , this might be that the function neglets the \r ? , search through the large dataset if it really has \r and

Comment: Yeah. Actually this appears to be the problem. Thanks to the comments here I found a flaw to my tests and the database actually doesn't have carriage returns like I thought it did. So the problem isn't the php string functions it's somewhere else that I'll have to find.

Comment: Just to let you know , faced kind of similar problem with unicode ! there's a character for unicode strings , and its a pain when in comes to DOM also !!!